# Pulling Data from MySql and dropping it into SQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I was wondering if anybody had any advice or references that explain how to pull data from MySQL and drop it into SQLSever! Any input would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks!

Comment: mysqldump, please take a lok to this link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_compatible

Comment: There are many tools to do this kind of thing. If you already have SQL Server, you can use SSIS.

Comment: It would be helpful to know if you are migrating to MS SQL Server or want to access data in MySQL.

Answer (score 3):

You can add MySQL as a **"linked server"**

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?60,123221,123221

Once you did that you can reference the MySQL  tables, views, etc with their fully qualified name in regular SQL Server queries

Answer (score 0):

I could not tell if you wanted to access a MySQL database because you were migrating to SQL server, or if you wanted to access a MySQL database on an ongoing basis. I am answering as if you want to migrate, because you already have an excellent answer on accessing MySQL from SQL Server.

If you want to migrate, mysqldump is one way to go. Its format is easily parsed.

You can also write the results of any MySQL table -- and SQL Server for that matter -- to .csv format. .csv format is nearly a universal transfer format for data.

Comment: Actually I am trying to pull data from MySql which is on hostgator and dump the data into a local Sql Server...

Comment: This sounds like the linked server approach is best, because you're doing that on a regular basis.

Comment: ok..I am going to go do some homework on it first and then I will try to implement this.

Comment: I would add this to my answer, but I have not done this work. My original answer uses a method I employ in production. Set up a bot to extract .csv into a location. Either the sending side ftp's data to the recieving side, or the receiving side ftp's from the sender. Then the receiving side inputs that data.

Comment: I have a quick question.....I have the New Linked Server dialog box open and I want to know where it says data source would I just input the IP address of the server on hostgator??